# How to add an entry to context menus in Nautilus?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a tool that works on Pharo packages (RPackages).

To make it accessible i want to add a menu entry to the Nautilus package context menu, so one can open my tool on selected packages from within Nautilus. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add entries to the Nautilus context menus you can use one of the menu pragmas that are defined in the `AbstractNautilusUI` `menu pragmas` protocol.

Just define a class side method with one of the pragmas on any class you desire. For example:

```
MyClass class >> myMenuEntry: aBuilder
   <nautilusGlobalPackageMenu>
   | target packages |

   target := aBuilder model.

   (packages := target selectedPackages) ifNil: [ ^ target ].

   (aBuilder item: #'Show my selection')
        action: [ self inform: packages ]
```

In the case of the Nautilus package menu you obtain the selection via

```
aBuilder model selectedPackages
```

Use the Finder’s pragma search option to look at examples.

(Thanks to Benjamin Van Ryseghem)